# Import "discord" could not be resolved, all module importing already done

Tags: python, pip, discord

I programmed a discord bot in python and I install all the needed discord.py libraries and everything was working fine. Today when I opened VSC, it shows me this error:

```
Import "discord" could not be found Pylance(reportMissingImports)
Import "discord.ext" could not be found Pylance(reportMissingImports)
```

Here is my code: (i dont think it has to do with this but whatever)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\code\\bot")

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "&", case_insensitive = True, intents = intents)
```

I've even done the pip module importing like:
`pip install discord`.
If anyone has some ideas of what I can do please post them in the answers.

Comment: The library you used is probably [discord.py](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/)? Then the appropriate pip command would be `python3 -m pip install -U discord.py`. Did VSCode pick up your virtual environment properly?

Comment: Try to restart your VSCode.

Comment: Both of those solutions still didn't work.